# How to plot a 3d graph in python where one of the axis is time

Tags: python

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

# Data for three-dimensional scattered points
zdata = df["TEMPERATURE"]
xdata = df['CAPTURE_TIME'].astype(str)
ydata = df["Power"]
ax.scatter3D(xdata, ydata, zdata, c=zdata, cmap='Greens'
```

I have written a code like above to plot a 3d graph wrt the Temperature , Time and Power . The time is in the format '00:00:00' due to which I am not able to plot a 3d graph. Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: do you have all data:00:00:00?

Comment: Yes. I have all data